# "Advising not to be dependent on ID column values, insTead prefer CTE"

Tags: sql-server

Recently I wrote a stored-procedure for selection query by filtering ID's like below :

```
create procedure procname(@compId as int)
as
begin
select Id,value,text 
from tableName
where Id not in(5,8,19)
and compId =@compId
order by text asc
```

Unfortunately my leads provided a mail as like

> Not advisable to be dependent on the Id column values here. An explicit selection of what they represent via a CTE(common table expression) is much preferred.

Here I'm unable to understand what they mean exactly by saying about CTE.

Comment: What is the `@compId` parameter for in your procedure? It is not referenced in your query.

Comment: edited please check once.

Comment: People that downvote without an explanation are anonymous cowards. Perhaps he/she downvoted because you have not added any explanation of why you are restricting the `id` to a certain set of values. All relevant context matters if you want to get a proper answer to your question.

Comment: Okay thank you @TT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your team leads are concerned that saying `Id not in (5, 8, 19)` may not have any meaning from a business logic point of view.  What I mean by this is that you are restricting your query to certain `Id` values, but these numbers themselves are arbitrary.

As an example of what might make the leads' warnings go away, if be there some column, say `some_col`, which all had the same value for `Id` values 5, 8, 19, and no other values, then you could modify your query as follows:

```
select Id, value, text 
from tableName
where some_col != 'some value'
```

Now, the logic behind your query is clear; you want records which don't have a certain value for a certain column.  If the `Id` values were ever to change, your original query might break, but this is much less likely now.  And if, at some later point, you would have had to add new `Id` values into the `IN` clause, you would not have do this now.

If you *must* refer to the `Id` values explicitly, then the leads advise that you use a CTE to take a snapshot of the underlying table.  This is another way to work around having random numbers hard-coded in your query, but I prefer my first suggestion, namely doing away with the IDs altogether.

Comment: I understood about your first suggestion. But unable why & how to prefer the CTE here. As far as I know is we'll go to CTE in case of recursive.

Comment: I think mainly they just don't want you hard coding these IDs into your stored procedure.  By creating a CTE the logic can be monitored, and ideally you would replace the hard-coded IDs with something more meaningful and stable.

Comment: If you understand can you please frame the code with CTE for the above query ?

Comment: @SreekanthReddy I don't think the structure of the CTE is the big issue here, it's really avoiding hard-coding values from an identity column.  Can you share with us the logic behind choosing 5, 8 and 19 value?

Comment: Actually here there is no much logic. as these were the dummy records. we are not including these id records.

Comment: But I understood that unnecessarily we should not include the IDs instead we need to go for the other columns with condition of text. So you mean based on the logic he might be saying to use CTE ?

Comment: They probably just want a CTE so that this component can be monitored outside your stored proc, that's all.  But once again, the big issue I see is with hard-coding those ID values.